# Is it possible to delete my postings?

Tags: discussion

Is there a way to get all of my postings to meta deleted?

I regret having tried to contribute something of value here.

Comment: Is it appropriate to ask about what happened that would make you desire this?

Comment: @AntonioVargas : I post polite and, in my view, thoughtful comments, and they are responded to with extraordinary degrees disrespect, often with people saying things that amount to telling me I'm a lunatic.  On "main" I am treated well; I don't understand the contrast.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: And if you flag the comments that call you a lunatic, are they deleted by a moderator? (If not I would would like to see a meta post on this).

Comment: @MichaelHardy I hope you change your mind. I'm aware of contributions you made here and on wikipedia. I know meta can be frustrating, especially when some users seem to be making intentional or inexplicable efforts to be at odds with you. I know that breaks make a big difference, like wikibreaks do. See you around (hopefully.)

Comment: *"Illegitimi non carborundum"*

Answer (score 9):

All posts submitted to an SE site are licenced under the Creative Commons license, which gives SE (and everyone else) permission to continue using the content, you cannot revoke the license you granted upon submission at some later point.

Removing all your posts would likely be disruptive and remove useful information from here (and not only the posts themselves, but e.g. all answers to questions as well), which is why it is not possible to do so.

Comment: And yet, when a user account is closed, all the user's postings to "main" are deleted and people lose their reputation points from answering those questions, without being told which questions are affected or which user's account was closed.

Comment: No, user deletion does not remove all posts (it removes all negatively scored posts, but not more). The reputation removal when a user is removed is somewhat annoying (I'm the author of the feature request on MSO to change that), but it is a bit better now that users with a lot of votes are handled separately.

Comment: The fact that one gives SE permission to continue to use the content posted doesn't mean that SE *should* do that.

Comment: @Thomas If you posts serve no useful purpose (anymore), you're free to delete them. But if they are useful, removing them would harm the site. And that is the point where the deletion will be reversed.

Comment: @MadScientist: Ok, I understand.

Comment: Wow, at least 577 upvotes for your [proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted) and it's still not implemented...